# How do I replace characters of a string, from right to left, cumulatively?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a function that receives a String, and replaces the string characters from right to left, by zero. Also, I'd like to make it accumulate and save those changes. For example:

String test = "12345678"

When I iterate through it, I'd like the result to be:

1. "12345670"
2. "12345600"
3. "12345000"
4. "12340000"... and so on.

Here's the code I've written so far:

```java
    public String test = "12345678";
    
    public String replaceFromRightToLeft(String test) {
        for (int i = test.length() -1; i >= 0; i--) {
            test.replace(test.charAt(i), '0');
        }
        return test;
    }
```

When I run it, I get results like:

1. 12345670
2. 12345608
3. 12345078
4. 12340678
5. 12305678
6. 12045678
7. 10345678
8. 02345678

So, what should I do to "save" the previous changes?

Comment: How do we check if it exists? Do we assume that you can do that?

Comment: SideNote: Make sure it is easy to replace such a validator for zip codes later. If you discover one day that you wish to process adresses from other countries, you will need different rules.

Comment: Please share your attempt to implement replacement

Comment: @MarceloMelo, you should use a char array of the initial string or put this string into StringBuilder and then you'll be able to modify the contents of the array/StringBuilder.  To print each attempt you need to create a new String instance of that array/StringBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

String are immutable so make a new string

```
String result = zip.substring(0,length-2) + yourNewChar
```

edit : i see in the comment `replace()` and it's better than what i write